# Pushing UIViewController - UINavigationController not resizing the view properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

Most of what i'm doing is in Storyboard using Segues and all works fine.

I've now had to create two seperate UITableViewCell xibs which i'm manually hooking up to push onto the UINavigationController.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    DetailDealViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailDealViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

However the (destination) view is larger than screen and it's dropping off the bottom. E.G: Using autolayout to position something to the bottom of the view doesn't show as the view is too high.
I've tried manually resizing it to no avail (although it does seem to work in viewWillAppear, but no ideal).

Generally speaking, using segues seems to work fine but manually pushing doesn't resize the uiviewcontrollers view.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what sense is the view larger than the screen? Is it a scrollview or tableview?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so that we might be able to get a better understanding of what really is happening.

Comment: Basically the view is the size of the screen including the navbar/statusbar so therefore it starts below the navbar and continues past the bottom of the screen and gets cut off. I'm not sure if a screenshot will help?

Comment: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5166676   - The view on the left is what's getting pushed onto the stack, as i've tried to demonstrate (badly) the view is too large and therefore the white box is being cut off.

Comment: my advice is to never use apples UINavigationController 'segue' or push and pop. stick with a straight XIB, do your own transitions with CA transitions/ animations and you'll stop having problems. This is my conclusion after over 5 years of ios